# Placing letters over each other / centering letters in a conainer?

Tags: html, css, position, center

I need to display one letter over another one in a link and want them to be CENTERED. I've tried postion: relative and absolute, but it's impossible to center the letters.

Any ideas? I want them exactly to be one over another, don't ask me why :)

Here's the code:

```
<a href="#">
    <span>O</span>
    <span>B</span>
</a>
```

All I know is the width of parent link, but have no idea what's the width of given letters.

Here's code to play width:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYhzJ/

**Edit**

Here's an example of how should it look like (it's not centered and I can't use negative margins if I won't know width of these spans):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYhzJ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/d7Qhq/1/

```
a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 100px;

    position: relative;
}

a span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: Sorry, I want them to be exactly in the center of the red circle, both of them, so one of them will be behind. Check the edit :)

Comment: Thank you, I knew there was easy way of doing that, just perfect!

Comment: Just as an improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/d7Qhq/2/, here you can easily change height, width and line-height, the rest adjusts automatically.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYhzJ/1/

adjust the height (and line-height = half of height) and padding to place the letters.

Comment: I want the letters to be exactly at the same spot, in the middle of red circle. Check the edit. Thanks!